# MPFR library: How can you add two mprf_t variables and print the result?

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision, mpfr

I'm searching for some example illustrating the `mpfr` library but I can't find anything useful.

I would like to create two variables that can hold up to 100 digits of a floating number.

These variables must be initialized using a string.

Then I would like to add them and print the result to the screen.

I found this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int i;
   mpfr_t s, t, u;

   mpfr_init2(t, 200);
   mpfr_set_d(t, 1.0, GMP_RNDD);
   mpfr_init2(s, 200);
   mpfr_set_d(s, 1.0, GMP_RNDD);
   mpfr_init2(u, 200);
   for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
   {
       mpfr_mul_ui(t, t, i, GMP_RNDU);
       mpfr_set_d(u, 1.0, GMP_RNDD);
       mpfr_div(u, u, t, GMP_RNDD);
       mpfr_add(s, s, u, GMP_RNDD);
   }
   printf("Sum is ");
   mpfr_out_str(stdout, 10, 0, s, GMP_RNDD);
   putchar('\n');
   mpfr_clear(s);
   mpfr_clear(t);
   mpfr_clear(u);
   return 0;
 }
```

then I tried the following code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  #include <gmp.h>
  #include <mpfr.h>

  int main(void)
  {
  unsigned int i;
  mpfr_t s, t, u;
  //add numbers 1.456774343454354355435354325213 and 
  //14.456774343454354355435354325213
  mpfr_init2(t, 200);
  mpfr_set_d(t, 1.456774343454354355435354325213, GMP_RNDD);
  mpfr_init2(s, 200);
  mpfr_set_d(s, 14.456774343454354355435354325213, GMP_RNDD);
  mpfr_init2(u, 200);
  mpfr_add(u, s, t, GMP_RNDD);
  printf("Sum is ");
  mpfr_out_str(stdout, 10, 0, u, GMP_RNDD);
  putchar('\n');
  mpfr_clear(s);
  mpfr_clear(t);
  mpfr_clear(u);
  return 0;
 }
```

result

`Sum is 1.5913548686908708384990518425183836370706558227539062500000000e1`

which is wrong it should be at least 2

Comment: Your result looks fine to me.  Did you notice the `e1` at the end of the string?

Comment: Also note that you're initialising `s` and `t` from doubles, so you've lost quite a bit of precision when converting the long decimal literals that you have to doubles.  You should only expect about the first 16 digits to be accurate, compared with the sum of the literals when interpreted as decimals.

Comment: Now you can also use `mpfr_printf` to output MPFR numbers. For instance, `mpfr_printf ("Sum is %.60Rf\n", u);` would output 15.913548686908708384990518425183836370706558227539062500000000, which is more clear here.

Comment: is it possible to use strings to initialize the mpfr classes so we don't use any precision during initialization?

Comment: @jsguy Yes, you can use `mpfr_set_str` to set a value from a string. See the [MPFR FAQ](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#accuracy) on the subject.